# DNS servers adresses not working after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns, 17.04

I've upgraded Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 and I can't connect to websites using the DNS servers that I've previously added in "Edit Connections"-"Auto Ethernet"-"IPv4 Settings"-"DNS servers" field in Ubuntu 16.10.

I had to go to "Edit Connections" in the "IPv4 Settings" tab and choose "Automatic DHCP" instead of "Automatic DHCP adresses only" to get my Internet connection working.

I'm using another Linux distribution on my computer and the DNS servers adresses are working normally. It's only affecting Ubuntu 17.04.

I deleted the "Auto Ethernet" entry in "Edit Connections" and recreated it, then I added the DNS servers adresses I want to use but it still doesn't work so I have to use my ISP DNS servers to connect normally to websites.

Is it a bug related to Ubuntu 17.04 and what can I do to use the DNS servers I want ?

Comment: Before any further troubleshooting I suggest you to fully update your system -> `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Reboot and try again.

Comment: I did and I still can't use the DNS servers I want. When I go to a website, Google Chrome says the server DNS address could not be found. Other apps also can't connect to the Internet normally. I have to go Edit Connections and delete the DNS servers adresses I've added to connect to the Internet normally. I tried Google DNS  8.8.8.8 and Open DNS adresses and they work. It seems it's the DNS servers adresses used in Ubuntu 16.10 before upgrading Ubuntu to 17.04 that don't work.

Comment: Same problem, clean 17.04 server install will not connect to anything.